# There is no AutoRenewable In-App Purchases option in iTunes

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, auto-renewing

I'm try to create an app with auto renewable subscription. But there is no auto renew option in list. 
Maybe I should make some preparations or it allowed only for specific categories?

[image: New In-App Purchases list]

Comment: Have you completed all bank info in the itunes?

Comment: Yes, it seems there is no linked card. I will link it & update question status

Comment: Update everything and it will show the auto-renewable option. Previously I faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a legal issue. Ask your team-agent or an iTunes User with de "Legal" role to check if all the in app purchase contact have been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that @Poles and @sivajee-battina are right - checked on another account with all bank info - auto renewable is available